# Where are the commands available in the man page window documented, and are these commands system-dependent?

Tags: man

Having used Linux for years, I suddenly found that I don't know how to use the `man` command properly. It is well known that one can type `q` to quit a man page, `/` to search, and others. I don't know, however, where are these documented. I tried `man man` `man -a man` `info man` and Googling, with no luck.

Please point me to the right position to look for this information, even if it is right in `man man` and I happen to have overlooked it, it's perfectly fine, just let me know.

Are these commands different for different OS or for different distributions of Linux?

Comment: Aren't man pages just viewed in `less`? (It is on my distribution, at least, and `h` shows a summary of `less` commands)

Comment: @Rastapopoulos *Aren't man pages just viewed in `less`?*  No.  [Because `less` isn't a standard utility.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/utilities.html)

Comment: I suppose you can use `readlink -f /usr/bin/pager` or `readlink -f $(which pager)` to find out which pager you have (by default `/bin/less`) than `man` the used pager. It may (should) work directly `man pager`

Comment: If you read your man pages using `more` or `less`, you can type `h` for help. (or you can just use `emacs`...)

Comment: @Hastur I tried `which pager` on both machines I mentioned in my answer (both are running CentOS) but I am not able to find one, not even with `locate`. It is always interesting to learn about differences between different Linux distros, although occasionally it can be annoying as well.

Comment: If you type `?` or `h` at the pager prompt, it should give you a list of commands.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is indeed right in the manual page for `man`, under the "Controlling formatted output" subheading and repeated later on in the "ENVIRONMENT" section for good measure:

> By default, man uses `pager -s`.

The manual page explains how there is a hierarchy of environment variables and command-line options (`PAGER`, `MANPAGER`, and `--pager`) for overriding the default.

This is how it reads on systems such as Debian Linux.  On systems such as Oracle Linux, in contrast, the `man-db` package has been built with a different default, which is however *still* reflected right there in the manual page in the same places:

> By default, man uses `less -s`.

The `man-db` package attempts to auto-detect, at compile time, which default pager to build-in to the command, and document in its manual page, out of `less`, `more`, and `pager`.

On systems such as Debian Linux, the `pager` command is part of the "alternatives" system and can map to one of several actual commands:

```
jdebp % update-alternatives --list pager
/bin/less
/bin/more
/usr/bin/pg
/usr/bin/w3m
jdebp %
```

So one consults *their* respective manual pages for how to drive them from the keyboard, according to which alternative has been chosen.  Usefully, the Debian alternatives system keeps the manual page in synch with the chosen command, so reading this manual page is quite straightforward:

```
man pager
```

Answer (score 5):

Man uses a pager to show the content.

The exact details depend on which version of `man` you are using.

For the version used on many systems:

- If the option `-p pager` is given then that pager is used.
- Otherwise if the environment variable `MANPAGER` is set it is used.
- Otherwise if `PAGER` is set it is used.
- Otherwise the default is to use `/usr/bin/less`

If the manual page is in HTML format then `BROWSER` is used instead of `MANPAGER`/`PAGER`

Debian uses `man-db` which has different defaults.

Read `man man` for the details

Comment: Thank you for your answer. While the answer does explain how `man` works, I would like to ask you if you can do the favor to point me to the right place where this behavior is documented. Thank you.

Comment: In my `man man` output (again, `man` version: 2.6.3) it states that "by default, less -s is used.", so I expect this is version- and system-dependent?

Comment: This is just an example of the standard Unix philosophy: small and simple commands that operate on text streams and do *exactly one* thing and do it well. Formatting a manual, and paginating are *two* things which is why they are performed by two different tools. This way, the pagination tool can be re-used for other tasks, not only for displaying manual pages.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Rastapopoulos, I find a line related to `less` in `man man` on a old Linux box (`man` version: 1.6f) in the **ENVIRONMENT** section that states,

> **BROWSER** The name of a browser to use for displaying HTML manual pages.  If it is not set, `/usr/bin/less` is used.

However on a newer box (`man` version: 2.6.3) this line has been replaced by

> **BROWSER**
>                 If $BROWSER is set, its value is a colon-delimited list of commands, each of which in turn is used to try to start a web
>   browser for man --html.  In each command, %s is replaced by  a  file?
>                 name containing the HTML output from groff, %% is replaced by a single percent sign (%), and %c is replaced by a colon
>   (:).

Based on these information I believe it is formatted in `less` by default (at least for the first case). However, even if this is the case, it is documented in a way that doesn't seem clear to me (or I have learnt the `man` command the wrong way).

Answer (score 2):

There's no real way to fully answer your question in general for various operating systems, as the `man` implementation isn't really that fully specified.

The POSIX-standard, non-Linux-specific answer can be found in [the POSIX `man` documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/man.html):

> **NAME**
>
> ```
> man - display system documentation
> ```
>
> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
> man [-k] name...
> ```
>
> ...
>
> **ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES**
>
> The following environment variables shall affect the execution of man:
>
> LANG
>
> Provide a default value for the internationalization variables that
>   are unset or null. (See XBD Internationalization Variables for the
>   precedence of internationalization variables used to determine the
>   values of locale categories.)
>
> LC_ALL
>
> If set to a non-empty string value, override the values of all the
>   other internationalization variables.
>
> LC_CTYPE
>
> Determine the locale for the interpretation of sequences of bytes of
>   text data as characters (for example, single-byte as opposed to
>   multi-byte characters in arguments and in the summary database). The
>   value of LC_CTYPE need not affect the format of the information
>   written about the name operands.
>
> LC_MESSAGES
>
> Determine the locale that should be used to affect the format and
>   contents of diagnostic messages written to standard error and
>   informative messages written to standard output.
>
> NLSPATH
>
> Determine the location of message catalogs for the processing of
>   LC_MESSAGES.
>
> PAGER
>
> Determine an output filtering command for writing the output to a
>   terminal. Any string acceptable as a command_string operand to the
>   [`sh`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html)`-c` command shall be valid. When standard output is a
>   terminal device, the reference page output shall be piped through the
>   command. If the PAGER variable is null or not set, the command shall
>   be either [`more`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/more.html) or another paginator utility documented in the
>   system documentation.

Note the RATIONALE section, describing why `man` isn't so fully specified:

> **RATIONALE**
>
> It is recognized that the man utility is only of minimal usefulness as
>   specified. The opinion of the standard developers was strongly divided
>   as to how much or how little information man should be required to
>   provide. They considered, however, that the provision of some portable
>   way of accessing documentation would aid user portability. The
>   arguments against a fuller specification were:
>
> - Large quantities of documentation should not be required on a system that does not have excess disk space.
> - The current manual system does not present information in a manner that greatly aids user portability.
> - A "better help system" is currently an area in which vendors feel that they can add value to their POSIX implementations.
>
> The -f option was considered, but due to implementation differences,
>   it was not included in this volume of POSIX.1-2008.
>
> The description was changed to be more specific about what has to be
>   displayed for a utility. The standard developers considered it
>   insufficient to allow a display of only the synopsis without giving a
>   short description of what each option and operand does.
>
> The "purpose" entry to be included in the database can be similar to
>   the section title (less the numeric prefix) from this volume of
>   POSIX.1-2008 for each utility. These titles are similar to those used
>   in historical systems for this purpose.
>
> See [mailx](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/mailx.html) for rationale concerning the default paginator.
>
> The caveat in the LC_CTYPE description was added because it is not a
>   requirement that an implementation provide reference pages for all of
>   its supported locales on each system; changing LC_CTYPE does not
>   necessarily translate the reference page into another language. This
>   is equivalent to the current state of LC_MESSAGES in
>   POSIX.1-2008-locale-specific messages are not yet a requirement.
>
> The historical MANPATH variable is not included in POSIX because no
>   attempt is made to specify naming conventions for reference page
>   files, nor even to mandate that they are files at all. On some
>   implementations they could be a true database, a hypertext file, or
>   even fixed strings within the man executable. The standard developers
>   considered the portability of reference pages to be outside their
>   scope of work. However, users should be aware that MANPATH is
>   implemented on a number of historical systems and that it can be used
>   to tailor the search pattern for reference pages from the various
>   categories (utilities, functions, file formats, and so on) when the
>   system administrator reveals the location and conventions for
>   reference pages on the system.
>
> ...

The paginator rationale discussion from [the mailx page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/mailx.html):

> The paginator selected when PAGER is null or unset is partially
>   unspecified to allow the System V historical practice of using pg as
>   the default. Bypassing the pagination function, such as by declaring
>   that cat is the paginator, would not meet with the intended meaning of
>   this description. However, any "portable user" would have to set PAGER
>   explicitly to get his or her preferred paginator on all systems. The
>   paginator choice was made partially unspecified, unlike the VISUAL
>   editor choice (mandated to be vi) because most historical pagers
>   follow a common theme of user input, whereas editors differ
>   dramatically.